# dynamic filtering axis in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to Power Bi and I have a question that I couldn’t find its solution:
I want to have a chart that shows the user a value in last 7 days (last 7 days till today),
How can I apply this dynamic filter on X axis?
Could anybody help me please out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Filters pane on the right you can select the attribute which you are using on x-axis and in the dropdown arrow for that you will see an option for relative filtering you can set it for the last 7 days there.

[image: Select Relative date option in Fiter type]

[image: Select "Is in the last" option in second drop down and then give # of days and select 'days' in the next drop down]

Comment: The problem is: this 7 days should be dynamic (based on today's Date) and in Filter pane I can just select static days

Comment: Hi, Check the updated screen shot in my answer. It will help to do the dynamic filtering on Date column in your graph.  In case you still not able to implement this then please share the sample screenshot of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks,but I cant see this 'relative' option

Comment: Check the data type of your date column. Also would be easier to help if you can share screenshots

Comment: But is there any other way to solve it with DAX? In case I want to show in axis just the values for today,same day in last week,same day in last week,I cant use relative filter.